# What's the maximum number of characters you can copy from a cell

Tags: sql-server, ssms

If you ctrl + c a cell how many characters do you actually copy?

I'm getting 43679 I was wondering if this is the limit of ctrl c? is this configurable? the real length of the cell is around 160k

- varchar(max) column
- MS SQL 2016 ver 13.0.16106.4
- Query Results -> SQL Server -> Results to Grid -> default 65k and 2mb xml

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11897950/1948808

Comment: There is no perfect way to do this, because SSMS was not designed to gracefully handle strings that large. The least messy way IMHO is to convert to XML, though this is definitely not perfect. See [this tip](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/).

Comment: @AMtwo unrelated

Comment: @AaronBertrand I know it's not designed to do this but I want to know what happens if you do it, I need to know if there is a exact length

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "what happens if you do it." 43,679 characters [seems to be a pretty standard limit in several parts of the SSMS GUI](https://www.google.com/search?q=43679+ssms). Are you trying to copy the value or just determine its actual length? If you're trying to copy 160kb from SSMS you're going to need to coerce it to display all 160kb first - that's where the links Andy and I shared are very related.

Comment: @AaronBertrand that is what I was looking for thanks I didn't think of actually searching the number

Answer (score 3):

The maximum number of characters you can render in most SSMS GUI elements is 43,679 (as [this search reveals](https://www.google.com/search?q=43679+ssms)). If you want to copy more, you'll need to either:

- extract it to a file
- use [one of the workarounds here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11897950/1948808)
- display it in the output grid in a different way, e.g. [by first converting it to XML](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3185/validate-the-contents-of-large-dynamic-sql-strings-in-sql-server/).